# Java/IntelliJ: shortcut to insert comment directly next to code instead of at start of line [macOS]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

When I use the default commenting shortcut in IntelliJ (cmd + `/`) it inserts the `//` comment line at the first position of the line like so:

[image: no comment]

Coming from vscode / javascript, I'm used to the commenting shortcut tucking the comment in directly to the left of the text of a line, preserving the indents:

[image]

Is there a way to modify the IntelliJ shortcut so that it comments the line of code using the format from the second example, rather than the first?

Comment: To do that I would have to hit command + left-arrow, then "/" and "/" for a total of four keystrokes. By comparison, cmd + "/" is two keystrokes. I don't consider doubling my keystroke count for a common operation to be acceptable simply because it's the default behavior.

Comment: Depends how often you need to comment-out code, I suppose.

Comment: Haha fair enough :) Check out the correct answer below from Konstantin Annikov, it may come in handy for you as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java > Code Generation** and untick "Line Comment at first column" checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! My sanity has been restored